# jQuery ajax not reaching root file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery ajax. But everytime I make the request from page ~/profile to the page ~/send_request the request is captured at ~/profile/send_request.
here is the code

```
function sendRequest() {
            var id = document.getElementById("button-request").value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_request.cshtml",
                data: "id=" + id,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#button-request").html(result);
                }
            })
        }
```

I am not able to get to the desired page. I have checked IE developer tools. From there I came to know about this issue!

Comment: Try with `"/send_request.cshtml"` instead of `"send_request.cshtml"` in `get()`

Comment: You’re probably calling the profile page with a trailing slash (`/profile/`) or you have a `<base>` tag pointing there. Try to have one canonical version and then redirect users requesting the wrong version to that. You can then adjust the path to `send_request.cshtml` accordingly (either with or without the leading `../` as in @Amith’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `/send_request.cshtml` instead.

Comment: are you using a testing server? It should work when deployed onto a server or an environment like MAMP.

Comment: Yes, I am using my testing server, my computer! Well in case I will mark it after 5 minutes the server isn't allowing my to mark as answers!

Answer (score 2):

If your .cshtml file is in the root directory use `../send_request.cshtml`